# Media Source Extension video crashed(Memory leak)

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, media-source

I've tried to use Media Source Extension(MSE) API to play live streaming over websocket. Everything works fine except the browser will be crashed for about one day. I also found that the memory would always increase. Below is my snippet. I guess that I append too much data so that the memory will always increase, which results in abnormal behavior for Chrome. Is that possible to release the MSE/ video buffer via MSE API to prevent the memory leak?

OS:
Windows 7 SP1 64 bit
Windows 10 64 bit

---

```
var buffer_size = 5*1024*1024;
var buffer_index = 0;
var video = null;
var frag_mp4_buffer = new Uint8Array(buffer_size);

websocket.onmessage = function(evt){
  var buffer = new Uint8Array(evt.data);
  if(buffer.length !=0){
    if((buffer_index + buffer.length) <= buffer_size){
      frag_mp4_buffer.set(buffer, buffer_index);
      buffer_index = buffer_index + buffer.length;
      if(sourceBuffer.updating == false){
        var appended = frag_mp4_buffer.slice(0,buffer_index);
        sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(appended);
        frag_mp4_buffer.fill(0);
        buffer_index = 0;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

---

Answer (score 2):

Use SourceBuffer.remove() api to remove content that has been played already, keeping a few seconds for any sync requirements.

Chrome does this as part of garbage collection, but I found it not very efficient when running a stream over several hours.

Also note, this doesn't solve the problem totally, but helps reduce the accumulation of memory substantially.